# Drag n' drop text file

Tags: html, text, drag-and-drop

I want dropped text files to be shown by their contents or their complete location so that I can load contents of that location into the "drop_zone".

This is what I have till now. I was just able to access the file name:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="drop_zone">Drop files here</textarea>
<output id="list"></output>

<script>
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();

    var files = evt.dataTransfer.files; // FileList object.
    document.getElementById('drop_zone').innerHTML = files[0].name;
  }

  function handleDragOver(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'; // Explicitly show this is a copy.
  }

  // Setup the dnd listeners.
  var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
  dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
  dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

here is the final code :

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="drop_zone">Drop files here</textarea>
<script>
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();

    var files = evt.dataTransfer.files; // FileList object.
    var reader = new FileReader();  
    reader.onload = function(event) {            
         document.getElementById('drop_zone').value = event.target.result;
    }        
    reader.readAsText(files[0],"UTF-8");
  }

  function handleDragOver(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'; // Explicitly show this is a copy.
  }

  // Setup the dnd listeners.
  var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
  dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
  dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works in Chrome but not in IE11? Any workaround?

Answer (score 6):

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ should be a good resource. You need to use a FileReader to read the contents of the file as a String.

Answer (score 0):

Due to security limits, a page isn't able to load contents of files without something like a Java applet set up with appropriate permissions; and, even then, it's not too possible.

However, that isn't to say it's impossible; simply upload the file to a server and echo the contents back out to the browser. That is how many text-editing-type web applications function.

How you implement this is up to you.

Further, as Maz has pointed out, you can also use built-in APIs to aid you in doing what you're trying to do. Do note, however, this solution is not necessarily cross-browser compatible.